# Rounding Percentages

Tags: microsoft-excel, tableau

Okay so I have been having a problem and would really appreciate any help. I have posted a table below with the aim of making this as simple/precise as possible.

```
 Value          %              Rounded %     Direction
 10     1.515151515151520%       2%              Up
 20     3.030303030303030%       3%             Down
 30     4.545454545454550%       5%              Up
 40     6.060606060606060%       6%             Down
 50     7.575757575757580%       8%              Up
 60     9.090909090909090%       9%             Down
 70    10.606060606060600%      11%              Up
 80    12.121212121212100%      12%             Down
 90    13.636363636363600%      14%              Up
 100   15.151515151515200%      15%             Down
 110   16.666666666666700%      17%              Up
 T660        102%
```

Table explanation: Value is a number (total=660). The % is the percentage of the total ((value/660)*100%). Rounded is the % rounded at the percentage level rather than rounding the total. Direction is whether the rounding is up or down. (row begining with T, = Totals)

Problem: I understand why I am getting 102%. I am creating a report that uses percentages and I want the rounded percentages to add up to 100% but be as mathematically accurate as possible. Is it possible to determine which decimals in the % column are most significant to the overall increase in the total percentage? Is there some universal equation that can be derived to perform this?

I know that this is pretty vague, so please comment if you need any clarification, but any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are trying to figure out which ones contribute the most to the rounding error, why not just subtract the rounded values from the original ones in a new column and look for the largest values in this column?

Comment: See this question for some options [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483430/how-to-make-rounded-percentages-add-up-to-100)